# Adobe Illustrator Color Error

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, hex

When I put a a color hex #ff00ff inside Ai, the hex number stays the same but the color gets darker and less neon. I've checked and the document was created in RGB mode, and I switched to CMYK and still have the same issue.

You can see an example of the correct color versus darker in the screenshot below:

here is #ff00ff properly displayed:

[image]

Here's how it renders when I use the same code in illustrator:

[image]

Comment: If you switched from CMYK to RBG color mode for the document setup, you need to reassign the color. By default, switching color modes does **not** update colors to match the new mode when going from CMYK to RGB..

Comment: It sure does look like #ff00ff converted to CMYK. Your *File > Document Color Mode* is set to *RGB Color*? And you haven't got *View > Proof Colors* checked? And your object has basic appearance with no effects or blend modes applied? You are not clicking the *Out of Gamut Warning* button? Does this happen in every new RGB document you create or only in this particular one?

Comment: Take a full screenshot of your illustrator. Thatway we can eliminate the obvious cases.

Answer (score 2):

A guess: You have proof colors "ON" and you simulate some CMYK printing process, no matter your document has color mode = RGB:

[image]

Switch View > Proof colors OFF if you are not interested in the look of CMYK print (sRGB ff00ff isn't a printable color in common CMYK printing processes)

BTW People pay to Adobe a substantial amount of money because Adobe's programs can predict what CMYK printing processes will output. If you are going to let a CMYK print house to print something you should also learn how to properly use color management.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not the issue. It was already set to OFF.

Comment: I wrote "A guess" because we know nothing of your color settings, proof color settings nor full document structure (= fill colors of the objects, layers, blending modes, opacity) Do not expect more than guesses without giving more info.